# Acer screen brightness cannot be controlled

Tags: backlight

On Acer Nitro laptop, I cannot control the brightness of the screen.

If I boot with kernel parameter `acpi_backlight=native` I get:

```
acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 4 - 0
```

If I boot with kernel parameter `acpi_backlight=vendor` I get:

```
Failed to set new screen percentage: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gsd_5fpower_5fmanager_5ferror.Code1: No usable backlight could be found!
```